# Embedding variables within Shopify settings.html

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

Is there a way to add templating into Shopify's `settings.html`?
I tried to just add the extension of `settings.liquid`, and allow the settings document to have [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) templating, but that did not work.

Within my `settings.html` file I have amongst other `fieldset`s the following:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Site Language</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Site Language</label></td>
      <td>
        <select name="language" id="language">
          <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
          <option value="es">Spanish</option>
          <option value="de">German</option>
          <option value="fr">French</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Languages to Translate</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Search - {{settings.language}}</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="lang_1" name="lang_1" size="30"/></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Is there a way to embed `{{langauge}}` within my Shopify `settings.html` file so that the settings are dynamic? I want the Site Language selection to be reflected in the legend of the following fieldsets.

Comment: Are you a Shopify Partner? There may have been some news on this recently...

Comment: @graygilmore Nope, just a user.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. Shopify will strip out any JavaScript you try to put in `settings.html`, too, so don't try going that route either.

Comment: And are there any other workarounds for achieving a dynamic settings.html file? And what I mean by dynamic is that some of the setting choices would alter the label or output of another setting choice.

Comment: Nope, you are unable to dynamically change any of the settings. Any JavaScript you try to add will be stripped from the page.